# Generalizing a property of $\mathbb Z_n$

Tags: ring-theory, commutative-algebra

Let $\mathbb Z_n$ be the ring of integers modulo n. Let $d_1,\dots,d_k$ be the divisors of $n$ excluding $1$ and $n$. Define $V_{d_i} = \{a \in \mathbb Z_n : (a,n) = d_i\}$ where $(a,n)$ denotes the greatest common divisor of $a$ and $n$. Then the set of zero divisors of $\mathbb Z_n$ is given by $$Z(\mathbb Z_n) = \sqcup_{1 \le i \le k} V_{d_i}.$$

Further, the sets $V_{d_i}$ satisifies

either $ab = 0$ for all $a \in V_{d_i}$ and $b \in V_{d_j}$ or $ab \ne 0$ for all $a \in V_{d_i}$ and $b \in V_{d_j}$.

I want to know,

1. In an arbitrary finite commutative ring with unity, is there any analog of the sets $V_{d_i} (1 \le i \le k)$ such that the above listed properties hold? or what are some other finite rings where such sets exist?
2. What is the equivalence relation on the set of zero divisors of a finite commutative ring $R$ with unity whose equivalence classes coincides with $V_{d_i} (1 \le i \le k)$ when $R = \mathbb Z_n$?

Thanks you.